# Why can't Python find the second function in my module?

Tags: python, module, python-import

Extreme Python newbie here. I'm trying to write some functions for the Black-Scholes option/greek formulas for LibreOffice Calc. I wanted to make one big module with various functions I will need to use in a few spreadsheets. I have them saved in a file called TradingUtilities.py. The first two functions look like,

```
def BSCall(S, K, r, sig, T):
    import scipy.stats as sp
    import numpy as np
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) - (r - 0.5 * sig * sig) * T)/(sig*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sig*np.sqrt(T)
    P1 = sp.norm.cdf(d1)
    P2 = sp.norm.cdf(d2);
    call = S*P1 - K * np.exp(-r*T)*P2;
    return call
def BSPUt(S, K, r, sig, T):
    import scipy.stats as sp
    import numpy as np
    d1 = (np.log(S/K) - (r-0.5*sig*sig)*T)/(sig*np.sqrt(T))
    d2 = d1 - sig*np.sqrt(T)
    P1 = sp.norm.cdf(-d1)
    P2 = sp.norm.cdf(-d2)
    put = K*exp(-r*t)*P2 - S*P1
    return put
```

When I run the script from the command line, the first function works fine. But I get the following error when I try to run the second,

```
>>> import TradingUtilities as tp
>>> tp.BSCall(238, 238.5, 0.05, 0.09, 0.09)
2.9860730330243541
>>> tp.BSPut(238, 238, 0.05, 0.09, 0.09)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'TradingUtilities' has no attribute 'BSPut'
```

I am trying to figure out what's wrong, but no luck so far. If anyone can see what I am doing wrong, or point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: the 'u' is capitalized in the definition and not in the call

Comment: Use lower case names in variables and functions with underscore-separator if needed. Only types such as classes should have capitalised names. That's the current recommendation. ``bs_call``, ``bs_put`` etc.

Comment: See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is typo in your code

```
>>> tp.BSPut(238, 238, 0.05, 0.09, 0.09)
```

should be

```
>>> tp.BSPUt(238, 238, 0.05, 0.09, 0.09)
```

Or you can change `BSPUt` to `BSPut` in main code.

Answer (score 0):

There is typo in your function name, compared to what you wrote in command line. Python is case sensitive.

It should be:
`def BSPut(S, K, r, sig, T):`

Comment: Dear Lord. I must now commit ritual suicide to redeem my honor.

Thank you, good sir.

Comment: Python is not just case sensitive for `"function names"` that is misleading and people may take this as `"only for function names"` Either remove that or be more clear as to what is consider case sensitive